# SDL_ttf and Numbers (int)

Tags: c++, sdl

```
int score = 0;
char* fixedscore=(char*)score;
.
.
.
imgTxt = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, fixedscore, fColor );
```

**^^ This doesn't work - looks like fixedscore is empty or doesn't exists.**

```
int score = 0;
char* fixedscore=(char*)score;
.
.
.
imgTxt = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "Works fine", fColor );
```

**^^ Works fine, but...**

I guess converting int to char* doesn't really work. So how do you print scores in SDL? 
Oh and one more thing: why is the text so ugly?

Comment: Ok fixed the problem with font being ugly by rendering it as "Blended". Now just need to be able to render numbers. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting is not what you want.  This code:

```
int score = 0;
char* fixedscore=(char*)score;
```

is the equivalent of doing:

```
char* fixedscore = NULL;
```

I assume you are trying to get `fixedscore` to hold the textual value of the number in score.  The easiest way using just standard C++ is via `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream strm;
strm << score;

...

imgTxt = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, strm.str().c_str(), fColor );
```

Comment: COOL BEANS!! Thank you very very much. :)
Had to add: 

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

But it's working now. Yay! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar problem,
I had

```
using namespace std;
int PlayerScore=0,AIscore=0;
stringstream Pscore,Ascore;
Pscore<<PlayerScore;
Ascore<<AIscore;

score1=TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, Pscore.str().c_str(), fontColor );
//Where score 1 is player1 surface on the screen
score2=TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, Ascore.str().c_str(), fontColor );
//Where score 2 is AI surface on the screen
```